# Undefined value when trying to use .substring()

Tags: javascript, arrays, substring, jsdom

I'm trying to check an array called `test[]` for the value `"Dep_"` and add it's value to another array `arrayDep`.

It's failing because it says the array at that position is `undefined` but in console log it is possible to see the array full of items.

Code:

```
jsdom.env({
    url: "http://www.camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/Dep_Lista.asp?Legislatura=55&Partido=QQ&SX=QQ&Todos=None&UF=QQ&condic=QQ&forma=lista&nome=&ordem=nome&origem=None",
    scripts: ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
    done: function (errors, window) {
        var test = [];
        var arrayDep = [];
        var value;
        var substring = "Dep_Detalhe.asp";
        var $ = window.$;
        $('a').each(function () {
            test.push($(this).attr('href'));
        });

        console.log(test);
        // inside console log:
        // 'Dep_Detalhe.asp?id=5830400',
        // 'mailto:dep.givaldocarimbao@camara.leg.br',
        // 'Dep_Detalhe.asp?id=5830706',
        // 'mailto:dep.givaldovieira@camara.leg.br',
        // 'Dep_Detalhe.asp?id=5830397',
        // 'mailto:dep.glauberbraga@camara.leg.br', ...

        for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
            value = test[i];
            if (value.substring(0,3) === "Dep_") { 
                // error occurs here it says:   
                // TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined
                arrayDep.push(test[i]);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If one or more of your `<a>` elements has no "href" attribute, you'll have `undefined` in some elements of the array.

Comment: @Pointy but wouldn't they appear in the log after `console.log(test);` ?

Comment: @Pointy i only have href itens inside my array i push only hrefs: test.push($(this).attr('href'));

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step through the code, rather than use `console.log`. I have sometimes observed that `console.log` logs inaccurate values.

Comment: Might be better to output each value of your test array to the console rather than just the automatic toString of the array itself. That way, you can debug which value is undefined in the array.

Comment: Adding a simple `alert(value);` after the assignment might point you at the offending item. It may also identify the any boundary values (first or last item in array for example) which might be the problem

Comment: Just check what are the values in the test array ....are you getting undefined value...may be the href attribute is null

Comment: @michelpm1 note that you will never get "Dep_" with `substring(0, 3)` it needs to be `substring(0, 4)`

Comment: @Comptonburger i used debugger and the value of the variable value here if (value.substring(0,3) ==="Dep_"){ is "#documentContent"

Comment: Since its looping inside the test array so test array has some values must be getting pushed into but the value that is getting is undefined ..thats it is throwing error here .

Comment: Is the value ==="#documentContent"  ?

Comment: I find undefined inside my array !! nice probably is that, i will try avoid it

Comment: just check after the other loop where you are getting value==="undefined"

Comment: you can write a condition like typeof value ==="undefined" then not to so substring

Answer (score 0):

It worked guys, my array was with undefined components, thanks to everyone, but the best tip was use the node inspector, with that was easily to verify my big array for undefined components.